# Django tracking data changes done by users

Tags: django, audit

How can i track changes on data done by django users and save them in audit tables with user_ID? Is there is any application what can do that? 
I'am using postgres and now for audit i'am using this util :  http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_rowlog/ but in this case i cant pass USER_ID into trigger..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`django-audit-log`](https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log)

Comment: will it save changes in some kind of table?

Comment: Yes. See the [usage instructions](https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log/blob/master/docs/usage.rst).

Comment: Ok, i see now, thank you. But this one create an audit table for every model - this is an overkill.